# Error while adding grid or hexbin layer in react keplerGL app

Tags: reactjs, grid, layer, deck.gl, kepler.gl

I am trying to visualized the data in keplergl using React app and wanted to add Hexbin layer but giving me errors.

Errors:

1. An error in deck.gl: Cannot read property '8' of undefined in nb74usl
2. An error in deck.gl: Cannot read property 'sortedBins' of undefined in nb74usl-hexagon-cell

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. Error appears after loading the dataframe into ``keplergl`` and switching into ``hexbin`` mode.